# R: Merge dataframes not aligning properly

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two data frames:

```
df1
    Day  Hour S_Value
    1    1    1
    1    1    2
    1    1    3
    1    1    1
    1    2    5
    1    2    6
    1    2    4
    1    2    2

df2
    Day  Hour n_Value
    1    1    3
    1    1    7
    1    1    na
    1    1    na
    1    2    1
    1    2    9
    1    2    na
    1    2    na
```

I used:

```
join <- merge(df1, df2, by = "Hour")
```

And got this data frame where the first number per Hour of the S_Value is filled in for all the same Hour:

```
join
    Day  Hour S_Value   N_Value
    1    1    1         3
    1    1    1         7
    1    1    1         na
    1    1    1         na
    1    2    5         1
    1    2    5         9
    1    2    5         na
    1    2    5         na
```

I want it to look like this:

```
join
    Day  Hour S_Value   N_Value
    1    1    1         3
    1    1    2         7
    1    1    3         na
    1    1    1         na
    1    2    5         1
    1    2    6         9
    1    2    4         na
    1    2    2         na
```

Comment: there are duplicates in the 'Hour' for both data

Comment: I think you need `cbind` ie. `cbind(df1, df2['n_Value'])` based on the example

Comment: There are multiple measurements for both S and N_Value at the same Day and Hour. cbind gives an error message. Is there a way to just add the column in the same order without trying to match them?

Comment: my suggestion of `cbind` was based on if both datasets have the same number of observations and if they are arrangred in the same Day, Hour.  It is possible that your dataset differ in number of rows.  `merge` or join doesnt work if there are duplicates for the key as it does a cartesian join

Comment: I just added a new column to each df ('Number') with consecutive numbering. I then did merge based on Number and it worked fine. Thanks for taking the time help!

Comment: Yes, that would work